# How to set custom sound for SMS from certain sender in MIUI 8.x?

Tags: xiaomi, miui, custom-sounds

I used to own Huawei device with MIUI 5, and there was an option to set custom melody for SMS from a certain sender (so you could understand if you received an SMS from this certain sender just by hearing the sound).

Now I own Xiaomi Mi5 with MIUI 8.1 and totally can't find such an option by myself: there is only option to set the sound for SMS on 1st and 2nd SIM-card.

Is there a way to get custom sound for SMS from certain sender in MIUI 8?

Comment: If you are fine with automation, try using [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid). Trigger: SMS received from (choose) Action: 1. Volume change> notification set to 0 (so that you don't get the normal sound) 2. Play Sound> choose 3 wait 5 seconds 4. Volume change (reverse action 1- so that for outlets you get the normal sound). MIUI and Huawei modding often do not conform to stock Android behaviour, so you may need to play around with other serums in actions 1 and 4

Comment: On second thoughts, simpler would be to replace action 1 by notification sound > choose sound and not have any other actions